# Disable Remember-Me in Spring Security & Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat, spring-mvc

I wonder, is there any way to disable remember-me in Spring Security?
Scenario I want to implement is pretty common: after closing browser window I would like user's session to expire. Seems weird, but it doesn't work with Tomcat 7 & Spring Security 3.1.
We use auto-config in Spring Security configuration file, but there is no remember-me element.

What is the best solution to get it working? Thanks in advance!

**Update** Here is the usage scenario to clarify my problem:

1. User logs into restricted area, say, /secure.html
2. Then he closes the browser without logging out manually.
3. He opens the browser again and goes directly to /secure.html.
4. Current Spring's behaviour: page is displayed successfully. Expected behaviour: redirecting to login page.

**New symptoms** for differential diagnosis:
User is probable reathenticated because JSESSIONID in the same between browser close/open. How I could forse Tomcat or Spring to generate a new session for every browser session?

**Update** Fragment of Spring Security configuration:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <anonymous key="anonymous-security" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/auth/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/auth/login.html" 
                default-target-url="/auth/default.html"
                authentication-failure-url="/auth/failed.html" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/auth/logout.html" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</http>
```

**Update** Documentation [claims](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ftn.d0e765) that there is no default remember-me configuration in auto-config="true" since 3.0 (we use 3.1):

> In versions prior to 3.0, this list also included remember-me
>   functionality. This could cause some confusing errors with some
>   configurations and was removed in 3.0.

What's wrong with my web app?

Comment: Is the remember-me cookie being set?

Comment: @artplastika: I may have misunderstood your issue, if not you might be very interested in the answer I provided below

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just logout the existing user by redirecting to: /j_spring_security_logout?

Comment: I consider it as a one of possible solutions, but then I need to store user's session ID somewhere in my DB, for example. Why do I need Spring Security then?

Comment: I don't clearly understand what exactly you need to do and why you need to store the session ID of a user after the user logs-out. Could you please describe it in detail?

Comment: If I would manually redirect to logout, then I need to determine that moment of session expiration. For example, user logs in secure area, then closes browser, then reopens the browser and opens secure area. When should I logout him? I suppose on the least step (his JSESSIONID will be different from ID that was before closing browser).

Answer (score 0):

In my implementation with latest Spring security and Tomcat 6, I am using the following configuration: Is it similar to yours?

```
<http use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/Error.xhtml">
    <intercept-url access="isAuthenticated()" pattern="/secure.xhtml"/>               
    <form-login />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/search.xhtml"/>
</http>
```

Comment: I have added fragment of my configuration to the question. It is close to yours, adding invalidate-session="true" has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a `logouthandler` to teminate the local session:

```
<!-- Logout handler terminating local session -->
<bean id="logoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
    <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="true" />
</bean>
```

In reality it defaults to true so you probably don't need the property to be set.

Comment: Defining a logout handler bean manually is the same as having <logout  /> element in my config. As I mentioned above, it doesn't take effect. It is reasonable, because this filter will get control when user logs out by his own. I need to invalidate session automatically if underlying  browser session has changed.

Comment: Yes, true. I wonder if perhaps the browser is showing a cached version of the page and you are seeing a copy or if there is a browser instance hanging around. Seems like what you have should work. It sounds like you are reauthenticating in the same browser session. You should be able to check the session ids to see if they have changed or are persisting between the open and close.

Comment: > You should be able to check the session ids to see if they have changed or are persisting between the open and close -- You are right, session ID is the same. Any ideas why and how to fix that?

Comment: This is strange. You might want to look at Tomcat. In Tomcat 7 the jsession ID should be invalidated right after authentication as they change it immediately behind the scenes. If you aren't using a servlet 3 specific deployment you should check to see if you get the same behavior on Tomcat 6. One of the biggest changes in Tomcat 7 is the security model improvements. Technically session ids should automatically be cleared when the browser dies. Also, you might want to check against different browsers to see if it is a cross browser issue.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem clarification:

I ran into the same issue: my browser would remember my user.

Typically: after logging in to access a restricted area, closing the browser, then reopen it and enter the same restricted area it would let me access it when I expected to be prompted for credentials.

After playing around I noticed one important thing: **this behavior is NOT consistent across browsers**:

- Eclipse's underlying browser does remember after closing
- Chrome does remember after closing
- IE (9) does NOT remember after closing
- Firefox (16.0.1) does NOT remember after closing
- Safari (5.1.7 for windows) does NOT remember after closing

More browser types & versions could be tested...

### Solution:

1. A work around may be to try detect when a user is closing his browser, and trigger a log-out when this happens. Not too sure how doable that is though.

There might be a better solution, I'll update this answer if I find it.