# spring security: inconsitent behavior across browsers for "remember me" feature

Tags: cross-browser, spring-security

The default behavior of Spring security (when `<remember-me/>` is not added to our security configuration) seems to be inconsistent across browsers (maybe across browser versions too).

Expected behavior: after logging-in to access a restricted area, closing the browser, then reopen it and enter the same restricted area, the browser should not let me access it but prompt me for credentials and let me access it only if I enter correct credentials.

After playing around I noticed this behavior is NOT consistent across browsers:

- Eclipse's underlying browser does remember after closing
- Chrome does remember after closing IE (9) does NOT remember after closing
- Firefox (16.0.1) does NOT remember after closing
- Safari (5.1.7 for windows) does NOT remember after closing
- More browser types & versions could be tested...

What I mean by "does remember after closing" is that the browser does NOT prompt me for credential after closing the browser and reopening it.

Spring is known to be very reliable so I may have missed something here.

My setup:

- Java 7
- Tomcat 7
- Spring Security dependencies version 3.1.2.RELEASE

Please enlighten me if you know of any solution to this problem.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071462/disable-remember-me-in-spring-security-tomcat

Answer (score 0):

A work around may be to try detect when a user is closing his browser, and trigger a log-out when this happens. Not too sure how doable that is though.